# Need A query to fetch data from two tables based on current system date?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I want to fetch the data for all the enquirers made on the current date. I want to match the current system date with that of Enq date in database and fetch the data from 2 tables from same date.-

```
protected void bindgv()
{
    DateTime from = DateTime.ParseExact(txtenqrydtfrm.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
    DateTime to = DateTime.ParseExact(txtenqdtto.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
    string wcenterid = ViewState["wcentreid"].ToString();
    //CONVERT(varchar, `enter code here`ActOnEnqNextFollowupDueon, 3)
    OleDbDataAdapter cmd = 
        new OleDbDataAdapter(
            "SELECT "+ 
                "enq.EnqStageID, "+
                "enq.WCenterID, "+
                "enq.EnqoffUseDetailsID, "+
                "enq.EnquiryName, "+
                "enq.EnquiryMobileNo, "+
                "enq.EnqEmail, "+
                "enq.EnqGender, "+
                "enq.EnqOccupation, "+
                "enq.EnquiryDate, "+
                "Actn.ActOnEnqNextFollowupDueon, "+
                "Actn.ActOnEnqBy "+
            "FROM "+
                "Wcpre_EnquiryOfficeUseDetails,enq "+
                "INNER JOIN Wcpre_ActiononEnquiry Actn ON Actn.EnqoffUseDetailsID = enq.EnqoffUseDetailsID where EnquiryDate between '" +tdate+"'",
                ConnectionManager.con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cmd.Fill(dt);
    `enter code here`
}
```

Comment: where is tdate ?, and whats wrong with the code

Comment: Basically: What are you asking? What problem do you face right now? Any exceptions generated? Is the piece of code you've written cannot generate expected result?
Adding more details to your questions can help you more and let us help faster and more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use parameters and your your sql statement change as `WHERE EnquiryDate  BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate`

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT  enq.EnqStageID,enq.WCenterID,enq.EnqoffUseDetailsID, enq.EnquiryName, enq.EnquiryMobileNo, enq.EnqEmail, enq.EnqGender, enq.EnqOccupation, enq.EnquiryDate,Actn.ActOnEnqNextFollowupDueon,Actn.ActOnEnqBy FROM Wcpre_EnquiryOfficeUseDetails enq INNER JOIN Wcpre_ActiononEnquiry Actn ON Actn.EnqoffUseDetailsID = enq.EnqoffUseDetailsID WHERE EnquiryDate  BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate", ConnectionManager.con);

dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", from);
dataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", to);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your trying to do here but as far as the SQL query goes. please replace between with "="

```
OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT  enq.EnqStageID,enq.WCenterID,enq.EnqoffUseDetailsID, enq.EnquiryName, enq.EnquiryMobileNo, enq.EnqEmail, enq.EnqGender, enq.EnqOccupation, enq.EnquiryDate,Actn.ActOnEnqNextFollowupDueon,Actn.ActOnEnqBy FROM Wcpre_EnquiryOfficeUseDetails enq INNER JOIN Wcpre_ActiononEnquiry Actn ON Actn.EnqoffUseDetailsID = enq.EnqoffUseDetailsID where EnquiryDate = '" +tdate+"'", ConnectionManager.con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                cmd.Fill(dt);
```